# C++ Signal QML Slot on registered type

Tags: c++, qml, signals-slots, qt5.4

I'm trying to call a QML slot on a registered type by raising the signal in my C++ code. The slot never gets called.

in main.cpp I register the type:

```
qmlRegisterType<MsgController>("MyStuff",1,0,"MsgController");
```

in msgcontroller.h I declare the signal:

```
class MsgController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
...
signals:
    void msgReceived(const QString& msg);
```

in msgcontroller.cpp I raise the signal

```
void MsgController::setMsg(const QString &msg)
{    
    emit msgReceived(msg);
}
```

and in my main.qml file I've got the slot for msgReceived:

```
import MyStuff 1.0
MsgController {            
            onMsgReceived: {
                console.log("message received:"+msg);
            }          
        }
```

The onMsgReceived slot never gets called. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Did you call setMsg()? It helps if you post code that is complete and runs.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling setMsg. I didn't post the whole thing so that people wouldn't have to read all the uninteresting parts.

Comment: You don't have to post the whole thing, just enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yeah I guess I should have posted another detail. There were two instances of MsgController, one instanciated in the C++ Sourcecode and one in the QML File. I connected the slot of the wrong object, that's why it was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't realized that I had connected to the wrong instance of MsgController in my code. One instance was created by the C++ code, but I really wanted to call the slot on the instance created by the Qml Engine.
Once I connected to the correct instance, the code above worked fine.